# How do I make a mute hotkey in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, audio, mute

Now, I actually already made a hotkey to mute the volume.

I got nircmd and put in this command, `Nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 2`. The problem is that it doesn't work when I start up a PC game (like battlefield or grand theft auto).

Now, it used to work when I had Windows XP 32 bit. I now have Windows 7 64 bit.

Is there a way to make it mute the volume when I have a game running? (on Windows 7 64 bit)

Comment: I gotta ask, are there volume control buttons on your keyboard?  Many keyboards have them and people forget they are there.

Answer (score 2):

You can make any disagreeable hot key with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) software.